# SQL Join two tables where one column goes to two different fields based on another field

Tags: sql

I have two tables reduced to the fields required do what I need.

**Deposits**

```
╔═════════════╦════════════╦══════════════╦═════════╦════════════╗
║ DepositDate ║ ThirdParty ║ IsChargeback ║ Gross   ║ DailyTotal ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2016-07-26  ║ 1000.65    ║ 0            ║ 5653.84 ║ 5653.84    ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2016-07-27  ║ 625.54     ║ 0            ║ 5438.98 ║ NULL       ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2016-07-27  ║ 0.00       ║ 1            ║ 394.39  ║ 5833.37    ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2016-07-28  ║ 0.00       ║ 0            ║ 2006.52 ║ 2006.52    ║
╚═════════════╩════════════╩══════════════╩═════════╩════════════╝
```

**Batches**

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╗
║ SeqNo ║ BatchDate  ║ BatchNumber ║ Gross   ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╣
║ 26    ║ 2016-07-26 ║ 98020841003 ║ 5653.84 ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╣
║ 27    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 072716MOADJ ║ 394.39  ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╣
║ 28    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 98020941003 ║ 5438.98 ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╣
║ 29    ║ 2016-07-28 ║ 98021041003 ║ 2006.52 ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╝
```

I want to join these two tables on the DepositDate and BatchDate. When IsChargeback is 1 on the first table, I need the Gross column to be Adjustments in the new table with Gross as 0. The last DailyTotal of the day needs to match the sum of the Gross totals. This is the expected output:

*SeqNo*: No duplicates in output

*BatchDate*: Should match *SeqNo* from *Batches* in ouput

*BatchNumber*: Should match *SeqNo* from *Batches* in output

*Gross*: If *IsChargeback* is 1 Then 0, Otherwise *Gross* from *Batches*

*Thirdparty*: If *IsChargeback* is 1 Then 0, otherwise *ThirdParty* from *Deposits*

*Adjustments*: If *IsChargeback* is 0 Then 0, otherwise *Gross* from *Batches*

**What I'm looking for**

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ SeqNo ║ BatchDate  ║ BatchNumber ║ Gross   ║ ThirdParty ║ Adjustments ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 26    ║ 2016-07-26 ║ 98020841003 ║ 5653.84 ║ 1000.65    ║ 0.00        ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 27    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 072716MOADJ ║ 0.00    ║ 0.00       ║ 394.39      ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 28    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 98020941003 ║ 5438.98 ║ 625.54     ║ 0.00        ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 29    ║ 2016-07-28 ║ 98021041003 ║ 2006.52 ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00        ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**What I've Tried**

The problem with my current query is that I'm getting two more rows than I want and since I need the top of one and the bottom of the other, I can't fix it with a group by. Here's my query and output.

```
SELECT 
    SeqNo, 
    BatchDate, 
    BatchNumber, 
    CASE IsChargeback WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE Gross END AS Gross, 
    CASE IsChargeback WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE ThirdParty END AS ThirdParty, 
    CASE IsChargeback WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE Gross END AS Adjustments, 
    IsChargeback
FROM Batches
Join Deposits
ON Batches.BatchDate = Deposits.DepositDate
╔═══════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ SeqNo ║ BatchDate  ║ BatchNumber ║ Gross   ║ ThirdParty ║ Adjustments ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 26    ║ 2016-07-26 ║ 98020841003 ║ 5653.84 ║ 1000.65    ║ 0.00        ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 27    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 072716MOADJ ║ 394.39  ║ 625.54     ║ 0.00        ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 27    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 072716MOADJ ║ 0.00    ║ 0.00       ║ 394.39      ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 28    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 98020941003 ║ 5438.98 ║ 625.54     ║ 0.00        ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 28    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 98020941003 ║ 0.00    ║ 0.00       ║ 5438.98     ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 29    ║ 2016-07-28 ║ 98021041003 ║ 2006.52 ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00        ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

What's the best way to do this?

**Update**

I tried the first comment, but results didn't match what I'm looking for.

```
SELECT SeqNo, BatchDate,  BatchNumber, 
       MAX(CASE IsChargeback WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE Gross END) AS Gross, 
       MAX(CASE IsChargeback WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE ThirdParty END) AS ThirdParty, 
       MAX(CASE IsChargeback WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE Gross END) AS Adjustments
FROM [Batches] b JOIN
     Deposits d
     ON b.BatchDate = d.DepositDate
     GROUP BY b.SeqNo, b.BatchDate, b.BatchNumber

╔═══════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ SeqNo ║ BatchDate  ║ BatchNumber ║ Gross   ║ ThirdParty ║ Adjustments ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 26    ║ 2016-07-26 ║ 98020841003 ║ 5653.84 ║ 1000.65    ║ 0.00        ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 27    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 072716MOADJ ║ 394.39  ║ 625.54     ║ 394.39      ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 28    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 98020941003 ║ 5438.98 ║ 625.54     ║ 5438.98     ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 29    ║ 2016-07-28 ║ 98021041003 ║ 2006.52 ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00        ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**Update 2**

I simplified the tables too much to start. I added some columns needed for the solution.

Comment: You should explain what the rules are for calculating each of the columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done

Comment: That's a comprehensive description. I wonder, wouldn't it be easier to build an example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the Gross field into Gross and Adjustment based on IsChargeback before joining lead me to the answer.

```
  SELECT 
        SeqNo, 
        BatchDate,  
        BatchNumber, 
        d.Gross,
        ThirdParty,
        Adjustment
    FROM [Batches] b Join (
        SELECT 
            DepositDate,
            CASE WHEN IsChargeback = 0 THEN Gross ELSE 0 END AS Gross,
            ThirdParty,
            CASE WHEN IsChargeback = 1 THEN Gross ELSE 0 END AS Adjustment
        FROM Deposits
    ) as d
        ON b.BatchDate = d.DepositDate AND (b.Gross = d.Gross OR b.Gross = Adjustment)
        ORDER BY SeqNo
    ╔═══════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
    ║ SeqNo ║ BatchDate  ║ BatchNumber ║ Gross   ║ ThirdParty ║ Adjustment ║
    ╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
    ║ 26    ║ 2016-07-26 ║ 98020841003 ║ 5653.84 ║ 1000.65    ║ 0.00       ║
    ╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
    ║ 27    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 072716MOADJ ║ 0.00    ║ 0.00       ║ 394.39     ║
    ╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
    ║ 28    ║ 2016-07-27 ║ 98020941003 ║ 5438.98 ║ 625.54     ║ 0.00       ║
    ╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
    ║ 29    ║ 2016-07-28 ║ 98021041003 ║ 2006.52 ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00       ║
    ╚═══════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you *can* fix this with `group by`:

```
SELECT SeqNo, BatchDate,  BatchNumber, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN IsChargeback = 0 THEN Gross END) AS Gross, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN IsChargeback = 0 THEN ThirdParty END) AS ThirdParty, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN IsChargeback = 1 THEN Gross END) AS Adjustments
FROM Batches b LEFT JOIN
     Deposits d
     ON b.BatchDate = d.DepositDate;
```

I removed `IsChargeback` from the `SELECT`.  It doesn't make sense, because it has multiple values within a group and the values are pivoted (in a fashion) anyway.

Comment: I updated my question with the output from that query. It didn't get me the output I wanted.

Comment: I posted the query output but SeqNo 27 should have Gross and ThirdParty = 0 and SeqNo 28 should have Adjustments = 0.

Comment: Added some additional info, I didn't give enough data to start.

Answer (score 0):

A minor modification of Gordon Linoff's should give what you require:

```
SELECT SeqNo, BatchDate,  BatchNumber, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN IsChargeback = 1 THEN 0 ELSE Gross END) AS Gross, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN IsChargeback = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ThirdParty END) AS ThirdParty, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN IsChargeback = 1 THEN Gross ELSE 0 END) AS Adjustments
FROM Batches b LEFT JOIN
     Deposits d
     ON b.BatchDate = d.DepositDate
group by SeqNo, BatchDate,  BatchNumber
```

Comment: Added some additional info, I didn't give enough data to start.

Comment: @ToddSkelton OK - not sure if this will help but try add this as the 7th column in your selects:    `(SELECT SUM(b2.[Gross]) FROM Batches b2 WHERE b2.[BatchDate] = b.[BatchDate]) AS DailyTotal`